# How to make spring repositories respond with html forms instead of json?

Tags: java, rest, spring-data-rest

I have multiple spring repositories, one for each table in my database. Using the `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackage = "com.company.repositories")` and `spring.data.rest.base-path=/api` in application.properties I now have a full REST api based on json.

I can POST to /api/customers, PATCH, etc but all with the help of JSON objects.

Is there a way to tell Spring to render html forms instead of json objects when I use GET on a resource and handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded when the forms submit data with PUT, POST, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsps to render the html with the help of ViewResolvers in spring mvc. In the below the new.jsp will have be rendered if validation fails.

```
//Controller example from spring doc
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@Valid AppointmentForm appointment, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "appointments/new";
    }
    appointmentBook.addAppointment(appointment);
    return "redirect:/appointments";
}

//Spring context    
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do I need to write forms in new.jsp ? I don't want to write code for 50+ entities I have in my model. Isn't there another way to do this ?